# Java-How to implement a custom map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) that can transform values of a Map given a function

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a custom sorted map. I want to transform each value in the map using map function. I know I can achieve this using java 8 stream().map(function). But I want to understand how the above map(function) works and write a custom function.

I have read several articles but I have not found one that is explaining clearing.

How I am doing it:

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> items = new TreeMap();//TreeMap is a custom implementation
        items.put("item1", 2);
        items.put("item2", 1);

      SortedMap<String, Integer> transformedItems=items.entrySet().stream().collect(
             Collectors.toMap(
                   ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry)->entry.getKey(),//pick each key as it is
                     ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry)->entry.getValue()*2, //transform the value here.
                     (val1, val2) -> { throw new RuntimeException("Not expecting duplicate keys"); },
                     ()->new TreeMap<>()
```

How I want to do it:

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> items = new TreeMap();
        items.put("item1", 2);
        items.put("item2", 1);

      SortedMap<String, Integer> transformedItems=items.customMap(value->value*2)
```

Challenge here is to write the customMap(function)

Comment: @Andreas I have my custom implementation of TreeMap so I can add a method

Comment: If you have a custom implementation, then you can add the suggested method in the answer with just the `valueMapper` as a parameter.

Comment: `SortedMap<String, Integer> result = new TreeMap(); items.forEach((key, value) -> result.put(key, yourFunction.apply(value)));` Is that what you want? It’s not like this logic was a magic secret. It’s [right in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a standalone `static` method that takes a value-mapping function. The method will do pretty much what your code does:

```
public static <K, V, R> TreeMap<K, R> mapValues(Map<K, V> map, Function<V, R> valueMapper) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                             e -> valueMapper.apply(e.getValue()),
                             (a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError("Not expecting duplicate keys"); },
                             TreeMap::new));
}
```

*Test*

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> items = new TreeMap<>();
items.put("item1", 2);
items.put("item2", 1);

SortedMap<String, Integer> transformedItems = mapValues(items, value -> value * 2);

System.out.println(transformedItems);
```

*Output*

```
{item1=4, item2=2}
```

Notice how the mapped value can have a different type, e.g.

```
SortedMap<String, Double> transformedItems = mapValues(items, value -> value * 2.5);

System.out.println(transformedItems);
```

*Output*

```
{item1=5.0, item2=2.5}
```

Comment: shouldn't returning a `Map` or `SortedMap`(return type) be preferred despite the implementation within `mapValues`?

Comment: @Naman Maybe, maybe not, that's entirely up to you to decide.